# How many sessions can Apache IoTDB be started and connected?

Tags: session, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask, can one Apache IoTDB server start multiple sessions and specify multiple ports? Is there any way to start an IoTDB instance, open multiple ports, and bind the thrift service to each port? What is the approximate number of sessions that can be connected by one IoTDB server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start multiple Apache IoTDB instances on one server by changing the port settings. In the stand-alone version, one port can reach to connect 10 sessions.